# Distributed Transactions and its implementation

Tags: java, transactions, jta, xa

I,ve searched the web all the way, but couldn't find a practical example of two phase commit in different databases and recovery in failure scenarios.
Can any one give examples of two phase commit in two different databases and how recovery happens in failure scenarios like failure of transaction due to DB service closed after it sent OK response of prepare and other DB queries are executed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You are here in the XA section. XA is a standard and defines how the different scenarios must be handled. Therefore this is not really vendor specific, however there are some edge cases that can be handled differently. Your best starting point would be to read the xa specs.

Comment: Hi, appreciate your response, can you tell me what's wrong am I doing in this: [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27728895/jta-xaresource-multiple-databases-what-if-two-phase-commit-fails-after-prepare)